# Docker Ubuntu: NIC Bonding

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, docker, network-bonding

I´m in the process of creating a docker image that supports nic bonding but the ubuntu 20.04 docker container throws the following error when I execute the command

## modprobe bonding

modprobe: FATAL : Module bonding not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic

I appreciate if someone could help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to do this from within the container, your issue is that the container shares the kernel with the host but not the filesystem.  Your host appears to be running kernel 4.15.0-20-generic and almost certainly has the directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic whereas your container, by design, has no kernel dependencies and thus no /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic directory.

Configuring your network from within Docker is generally bad practice and doubly so if it requires loading of kernel modules.  If you really want to do this, you can module your host's kernel modules into the container using something like `-v /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic:/lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic:ro` and, since you'll be messing with the kernel, you will also want to launch the container with the `--privileged` flag.

Comment: This command "docker run -it --privileged --cap-add=all -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules ubuntu" helps. But when I commit and push to the hub I do not see the kernel modules if imported from the hub. Appreciate if you could help me to fix.

Comment: Volumes/mounts (the `-v`) don't get committed into the image.  if you don't use volumes/mounts, the image has to be tailored to each kernel that the image might every be hosted on which is a bit difficult.  As I previously said, this is not a great use-case for docker.